# WAMP 3.1 setup on Windows 10. Can't access online

Tags: apache, wamp, virtual-hosts

I've been trying two days straight to make this work. I want to make my server available online so I can work with another guy on this project. The goal is mainly to have two things:

- The www website available through my public ip
- MySQL available to him so he can work

This computer has:

- Windows 10 Pro
- WAMP 3.1
- Node.JS

I went through the configuration of the vhost of wamp, port forwarding in my router and this doesn't work:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 192.168.2.51
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I put back what was in http.conf because that's the first thing I modified at first until I discover the new WAMP wasn't using this anymore.

I though Node.JS could conflict so I shut it down. I also shut most process using port 80 but still no luck.

I used an online port checker. The result is positive and it seems to go through, at least from their POV. And I did a netstat to check if I had 0.0.0.0:80 so everything seems fine on that side.

The port 80 tester of WAMP even says it's fine so I'm guessing it must be in the Virtual host but I have no idea how to set it up properly and documentation is not helping a lot.

What am I missing?

regards,

Comment: If you telnet port 80 of the public IP, what is the response?

Comment: It's doing nothing. Blank, so this is usualy a good sign and it should be ok. Right?

Comment: `telnet` response can either be "Connected" , "Connection Timed Out" or "Connection refused". Empty response is impossible.

Comment: When I research for empty response, it seems to tell it's a normal behavior if it's going well. I use the command and then it refresh and goes black (blank). What would be the command? I used "Telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80". Any other port give me "Connect Failed".